# jquery validate and bootstrap btn. Error placement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my jquery validation error message placement. It looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FPPiOJ2.jpg]

The error message is being applied into the button.

this is my radio group

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Gender</label>   
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female
            </label>   
        </div>
    </div>

$(function(){
    $("#formTest").validate({
        rules : {
            gender : {
                required: true
                     }
                },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `errorPlacement` *callback* to control validation error message placement, `insertBefore` or `insertAfter` any elements you want.

For example, in your case you can place the validation error after `.control-label` class, like this:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(".control-label");
},
```

and you can use the `errorElement` option to change element from `label` into a `div`. *(default: 'label')*

```
errorElement: 'div',
```

Finally your JS code looks like:

```
$(function(){
$("#formTest").validate({
    rules : {
        gender : {
            required: true
                 }
            },

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(".control-label");
    },

    errorElement: 'div',
});
});
```

See [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/2kLjznmt/), *I hope it works for you, Thanks !*